# When Wifi disconnect, how does Socket on Android server side know that?

Tags: android, sockets, wifi

I developed an Android app, which works in Wifi AP mode as a Socket server. Some clients setup Wifi connection and socket connection with my app. When the socket is connected, I disconnect the Wifi connection from the client, however there is no exception nor the read method of socket return **-1** in my server app. My questions are:

1. How to detect the broken wifi connection
2. How to detect which client's wifi connection is broken

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use this in a Thread

```
public static boolean checkNetworkConnection(Context context)   
{   

   final ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);   

   final android.net.NetworkInfo wifi =connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);   
   final android.net.NetworkInfo mobile =connMgr.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);   

   if(wifi.isAvailable()||mobile.isAvailable())   
       return true;   
   else  
       return false;   
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But in my situation, there are several Wifi connections with my AP. getNetworkInfo() method returns which one of them?

Comment: @yinhao try WifiManager wifi = (WifiManager)(this.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE)); WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiManager.getConnectionInfo(); the wifiInfo has some state

Comment: Thanks again for your reply. However there are several Wifi connections. getConnectionInfo return which one? I think this method is used on Wifi Client side instead of AP server side. Because on client side, there is only one Wifi connection.